# Stored procedure with specific month and year not working as input parameters when the EXEC the query ...?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with creating a stored procedure using specific month and year as input perimeters.

I need to create a stored procedure called `sp_products` listing a specified product ordered during a specified month and year. The product name, month, and year will be input parameters for the stored procedure. Display the product name, unit price, and units in stock from the `Products` table, and the supplier name from the `Suppliers` table. Use the following query to test your stored procedure to produce the result set listed below.

```
EXEC sp_products '%tofu%', 'December', 1992

ProductName UnitPrice UnitsInStock Name
------------------------------ -------------- --------------- -----------------------------------
```

Here is the code I have written the query executed successfully.

But when I ran the

```
EXEC sp_products '%tofu%', 'December', 1992
```

I'm getting error messages.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_products
   (@product VARCHAR(40),
@month DATETIME = 'December',
@year DATETIME = 1992
   ) 
AS
   SELECT             
      P.ProductName, P.UnitPrice, P.UnitsInStock,
      S.Name
   FROM 
      Products P
   INNER JOIN 
      Suppliers S ON P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID 
   WHERE 
      P.SupplierID = @product
```

Need help.....!!!!

Comment: are you sure you are using `MySQL`? I think it's `SQL Server`.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can cantenate the pattern on the stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_products
(         
    @product VARCHAR(40),
    @month DATETIME,
    @year DATETIME
)
AS
SELECT  P.ProductName,
        P.UnitPrice,
        P.UnitsInStock,
        S.Name
FROM    Products P
        INNER JOIN Suppliers S 
            ON P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID 
WHERE   P.SupplierID = '%' + @product + '%'

GO
```

Executing Proc,

```
EXEC sp_products 'tofu', 'December', 1992
```

*Follow-up question: what is the use of `@month` and `@year` parameters?*